# Using paginator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-paginator

I'm using paginator first time, and now I have some questions how to and where to do things.

Here my ideas and underneath some code.

I understood to object paginator in my controller action, give the object to my datacollection an give this to my ViewModel Object.

Because I get an error about the ArrayAdapter I will post also the error and my use statements in my controller class.

error:

> Class 'Stammdaten\Controller\ArrayAdapter' not found

**xyzController.php**

```
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Paginator\ScrollingStyle\Sliding;

public function indexAction()
    {
        $page  = $this->params()->fromRoute('page');
        $paginator= new Paginator(new ArrayAdapter($this->mandantTable->Ansprechpartnerjoin()->toArray()));
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
        $paginator->setPageRange(5);
        return new ViewModel([
                      'paginator' => $paginator,
            ]);

    }
```

First question here: Is this adapter the right one, because I give a tableadapter collection or do I have to change to another adapter?

I modified my routing for using paginator like follows:

**module.config.php**

```
'router' => [
            'routes' => [
                'mandant' => [
                    'type'    => Segment::class,
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/mandant[/:action[/:id[/:page]]]',
                        'constraints' => [
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'id'     => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*',
                        ],
                        'defaults' => [
                            'controller' => Controller\MandantController::class,
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],

                'paginator' => [
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => [
                        'route' => '/list/[page/:page]',
                        'defaults' => [
                            'page' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],


            ],
        ],
```

Next question here: is it needed to modify the route for MandantController as well or would it be enough to have the paginator route?

**And here part of my viewscript, index.phtml:**

```
foreach ($this->paginator->getCurrentItems() as $mandant) :?>
     <tr>
         <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($mandant['somefield']) ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach;

echo $this->paginator, 'Sliding', 'pagination/control', array('route' => 'mandant')
?>
```

Next Question here, I gave the paginator object to an array, because of the arrayadapter, but I really would prefer to have an object rather than an array, is this possible or do I have to use another adapter?

And last question: Is everything done or am I missing something somewhere?

EDIT 1:
I tried a bit further, and have now changed to the DbSelect Adapter, but it seems like my tableadapter won't be accepted. This is what I changed now:

**xyzController.php**

```
     $page  = $this->params()->fromRoute('page');

            $countQuery = new Select();
            $countQuery
            ->from('t_mandant')
            ->columns([ DbSelect::ROW_COUNT_COLUMN_NAME => 'id' ]);

$paginator= new Paginator(new DbSelect($this->mandantTable->Ansprechpartnerjoin(),null, $countQuery));
            $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
            $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(20);
            $paginator->setPageRange(5);
            return new ViewModel([
                'paginator' => $paginator,

            ]);
```

The error message:

> Argument 1 passed to Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Zend\Db\Sql\Select, instance of
>   Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet given

This is of course right, my question is, what do I have to do, to give the tableAdapter instance to the paginator constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I changed to another solution. I construct  the paginator in my model.

It now looks like follows:

```
 $resultSetprototype=new ResultSet();
        $resultSetprototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Mandant());
        $paginatorAdapter= new DbSelect($select, $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(), $resultSetprototype);
        $paginator=new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
        return $paginator;
```

Now it works quite well.

Comment: Please accept your own answer or remove the question.